# mswin.vim key bindings

Tags: key-bindings

I'm using MS Windows shortcuts for vim by editing my `vimrc`:

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin
```

I'm missing key bindings for Control+F to access find functionality and Control+S to save a file. I know there is the possibility to define those mappings manually e.g. `:imap <C-f> <C-o>/` for insert mode. Why those mappings have been left out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because either nobody uses mswin.vim and uses the usual/standard vi commands or nobody has complained that those maps are missing. If you want to have those maps included in mswin.vim you might want to open an issue at the vim/vim repository and mention that. Even better would be, to directly contribute those maps by creating a pull request.

Comment: I seem to remember that they may be commented out, but I haven't checked and may have commented them out in my copy anyway.

Comment: Note, this has just been added to [mswin.vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/8cc2a9c062fa38e133a62778518f769a423a2526)